# Python: How to call unbound method with other type parameter?

Tags: python, methods

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15)
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object):
...     def f(self):
...             print self.k
...
>>> class B(object):pass
...
>>> a=A()
>>> b=B()
>>> a.k="a.k"
>>> b.k="b.k"
>>> a.f()
a.k
>>> A.f(a)
a.k
>>> A.f(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
>>>
```

How can I do this?

Edited:this example is more clear

Comment: It's unusual to need to do this. Are you are you can't use the `staticmethod` decorator to solve your problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `im_func` attribute of the method.

```
A.f.im_func(b)
```

Comment: In Python 2.6+, you can also use `A.f.__func__` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html))